# Getting Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type error

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following code do try to avoid using switch/case or if statements:

```
function getReason(reasonNumber: number) {
    let fn;

    const reasons = {
        0: function() {
            return "Activation"
        },
        1: function() {
            return "Downgrade"
        },
        2: function() {
            return "Upgrade"
        },
        3: function() {
            return "Cancellation"
        },
        4: function() {
            return "Incompatibility"
        }
    }

    fn = reasons[reasonNumber]

    return fn();
}
```

The thing is that I'm getting an TypeScript error on `fn = reasons[reasonNumber]`, the error is:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ 0: () => string; 1: () => string; 2: () => string; 3: () => string; 4: () => string; }'.`

`No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ 0: () => string; 1: () => string; 2: () => string; 3: () => string; 4: () => string; }'.`

I tried reading about indexable types but I didn't understand how I can use them on this case. Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error itself isn't completely clear, I believe it's because you have the possibility of calling `getReason` with an unsupported number (anything above 4). If this were to run, it would error because undefined is not a function.

The safest way to handle it within this function is to only allow specific numbers:

```
function getReason(reasonNumber: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) {
    let fn;

    const reasons = {
        0: function() {
            return "Activation"
        },
        1: function() {
            return "Downgrade"
        },
        2: function() {
            return "Upgrade"
        },
        3: function() {
            return "Cancellation"
        },
        4: function() {
            return "Incompatibility"
        }
    }

    fn = reasons[reasonNumber]

    return fn();
}

getReason(1) // allowed
getReason(5) // not allowed
```

This might simply move the type error to where `getReason` is called though. If you prefer, handling the error internally, or providing a sensible fallback value would work:

```
function getReason(reasonNumber: number): string {
    const reasons: Record<string, () => string> = {
        0: function() {
            return "Activation"
        },
        1: function() {
            return "Downgrade"
        },
        2: function() {
            return "Upgrade"
        },
        3: function() {
            return "Cancellation"
        },
        4: function() {
            return "Incompatibility"
        }
    }

    if (reasons[reasonNumber]) {
      const fn = reasons[reasonNumber]
      return fn()
    } else {
      // Either handle the error, or return a default...
      throw new Error('')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object keys can't be numbers in JS, they are converted intro strings.
So in your case you'll need to change the type from `number` to `string` to make it work.

Alternatively you can convert to string before accessing the key
Edit: you'll also need to define the type of `reasons` to have keys of type `string`

```
function getReason(reasonNumber: number) {
    let fn;

    const reasons: Record<string, () => string> = {
        0: function() {
            return "Activation"
        },
        1: function() {
            return "Downgrade"
        },
        2: function() {
            return "Upgrade"
        },
        3: function() {
            return "Cancellation"
        },
        4: function() {
            return "Incompatibility"
        }
    }

    fn = reasons[String(reasonNumber)]

    return fn();
}
```

To take this even further you could make `reasons` your source of truth:

```
const reasons = {
  0: function () {
    return "Activation"
  },
  1: function () {
    return "Downgrade"
  },
  2: function () {
    return "Upgrade"
  },
  3: function () {
    return "Cancellation"
  },
  4: function () {
    return "Incompatibility"
  }
}
type ReasonNumber = keyof typeof reasons
function getReason(reasonNumber: number) {
  let fn;

  fn = (reasonNumber in reasons) ? reasons[reasonNumber as ReasonNumber] : undefined

  return fn();
}
```

Notice that now TS complains that `fn` might be undefined and requires you to check `fn` before executing it.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm supposed to receive a number as a parameter on this function, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Now I'm getting Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

That's probably due to noImplicitAny configuration on the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I ended up using a Record and it works as well but your answer works too. Thank you!